# trying to get image to fill whole left side

Tags: css, sass

I am developing a page in my WordPress site that displays the websites I have worked on when I hover over the title of the project on the right hand side. Right now it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the image is not filling out the whole left side and that is my question. How do I get it to fill out the whole left side in css?

This is my _acf-work-portfolio.scss file:

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Work Portfolio
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.work-entry {
  display: block;

  .work-left {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
  }
  .work-right {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 100px 25px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;

        li {
            margin-top: 50px;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
        }
  }

  .item {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    &.active {
        display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

I should be able to just tweak the class of item, but I have been unable to solve it.

Comment: what do you mean by filling out the whole left side ?

Comment: @Qchmqs, for the image to fill out that whole green block on the left

Comment: set height and width to 100% ?

Comment: @Qchmqs, can you post that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set height and width to 100% in the .item element

.item {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}